# What does 'WWF piledriver' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

While reading Scott Aaronson's *Quantum Computing Since Democritus*, I came across this passage:

> But what if you want to apply quantum mechanics to the whole
>   universe, including yourself? The answer, in the epistemic-type interpretations, is simply that you don’t ask that sort of question! Incidentally, that was Bohr’s all-time favorite philosophical move, his WWF
>   piledriver: “You’re not allowed to ask such a question!”

While I can mostly infer what is meant here from context, to what does 'WWF piledriver' refer in this paragraph?

(Searching the web suggests something wrestling-related, but very little other than that, and there seems to be no pro-wrestling SE.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piledriver_(professional_wrestling)

Comment: WWF is the old name of a wrestling promotion company.  Their current name is "WWE".

Answer (score 4):

WWF was the former abbreviated name for what is now known as WWE, or World Wrestling Entertainment - they lost a trademark lawsuit against the World Wildlife Fund, known as WWF in the U.K., and changed their name.

A piledriver is a wrestling move which often finish off an opponent in a bout: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piledriver_(professional_wrestling)

So this was Bohr's 'finishing move'